# Python and Pyinstaller files

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I packaged a program on Python using PyInstaller (on Centos), output is 8 files in 
/var/pyinstaller/pyinstaller-2.0/test/build/pyi.linux2/test :

```
out00-PYZ.toc
out00-PYZ.pyz
out00-PKG.toc
out00-PKG.pkg
out00-EXE.toc
out00-COLLECT.toc
out00-Analysis.toc
test                     // thats project file name. test.py
```

My question is how can now use this files to run programm on CentOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the /var/pyinstaller/pyinstaller-2.0/test/dist/test folder. The build folder is a throw-away by-product of the distribution build process.

good luck

Mike